# Can we acces files in second operating system on the computer?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have two windows 8.1 on my computer but unfortunately one of them is out of use because of an update problem. Now I need a file on that OS which resides in Desktop. Can I acces that file from the other OS which I can use now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can. As long as the OS supports the file system

Comment: How do I know if it supports?

Comment: depends on the OS and the file system. For example, if new OS is also Windows, then you can access the older one. If the older system was on NTFS, any OS which supports NTFS can access it.

Comment: Both of them are Windows 8.1 I installed them at the same time. So probably everything is the same for both. How can I do that? I couldn't find any link on the internet.

Comment: I hope you have installed new 8.1 on different partition. Just open old partition, it will be mostly C drive. In that, you can find under: `Users/your-username/Desktop`